# I am changing the scale size of the canvas from webgl to hammer.js

Tags: hammer.js

It is being developed so that hair image can be corrected using the spine program.

This is the test url:

- https://bxkrl.com/maskon-master/public/hair.html

In this example, `hammer.js` is used to increase and decrease the canvas scale.

If you increase or decrease the scale of the canvas, there is a difference in the image correction touch point.

[image: [Image usage examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwGzz.png)]

To adjust the different touch points, I need to change x and y. How should I change them according to the change of scale?

`hair.html`:

```html
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="aspect standalone"></div>
    </center>
    <script>
        spineDemos.init();
        spineDemos.addDemo(vineDemo, document.getElementsByClassName("aspect")[0]);
    </script>
</body>
```

`hair_1.js`:

```js
var vineDemo = function(canvas, bgColor) {
    var COLOR_INNER = new spine.Color(0.0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    var COLOR_OUTER = new spine.Color(0.0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    var COLOR_INNER_SELECTED = new spine.Color(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0);
    var COLOR_OUTER_SELECTED = new spine.Color(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0.0);

    var canvas, gl, renderer, input, assetManager;
    var skeleton, state, bounds, position;
    var target = null;
    var hoverTargets = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
    var controlBones = [
        "bone2", "bone3", "bone4", "bone5", "bone6", "bone7", "bone8", "bone9", "bone10", "bone11", "bone12", "bone13", "bone14", "bone15", "bone16", "bone17", "bone18", "bone19", "bone20", "bone21", "bone22", "bone23", "bone24", "bone25", "bone26", "middlebone1", "middlebone2", "middlebone3", "middlebone4", "middlebone5", "middlebone6", "middlebone7", "middlebone8", "middlebone9", "middlebone10", "bone27", "bone28", "bone29", "bone30", "bone31", "bone32"
    ];
    var coords = new spine.Vector3(),
        temp = new spine.Vector3(),
        temp2 = new spine.Vector2();

    bgColor = new spine.Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.context = new spine.ManagedWebGLRenderingContext(canvas, {
        alpha: true,
        premultipliedAlpha: false
    });

    function init() {
        gl = canvas.context.gl;
        renderer = new spine.SceneRenderer(canvas, gl);
        input = new spine.Input(canvas);
        assetManager = new spine.AssetManager(gl, spineDemos.path, spineDemos.downloader);

        assetManager.loadTextureAtlas("skeleton.atlas");
        assetManager.loadJson("skeleton.json");
    }

    function loadingComplete() {
        var atlasLoader = new spine.AtlasAttachmentLoader(assetManager.get("skeleton.atlas"));
        var skeletonJson = new spine.SkeletonJson(atlasLoader);
        var skeletonData = skeletonJson.readSkeletonData(assetManager.get("skeleton.json"));
        skeleton = new spine.Skeleton(skeletonData);
        skeleton.setToSetupPose();
        skeleton.updateWorldTransform();
        var offset = new spine.Vector2();
        bounds = new spine.Vector2();


        skeleton.getBounds(offset, bounds, []);
        skeleton.updateWorldTransform();

        skeleton.color = {
            r: 0.2,
            g: 0.2,
            b: 0.2,
            a: 1
        };

        renderer.camera.position.x = offset.x + bounds.x / 2;
        renderer.camera.position.y = offset.y + bounds.y / 2;

        renderer.skeletonDebugRenderer.drawMeshHull = false;
        renderer.skeletonDebugRenderer.drawMeshTriangles = false;

        setupUI();
        setupInput();
    }

    function setupUI() {
        renderer.skeletonDebugRenderer.drawPaths = false;
        renderer.skeletonDebugRenderer.drawBones = false;
    }

    function setupInput() {
        input.addListener({
            down: function(x, y) {
                target = spineDemos.closest(canvas, renderer, skeleton, controlBones, hoverTargets, x, y);
            },
            up: function(x, y) {
                target = null;
            },
            dragged: function(x, y) {
                spineDemos.dragged(canvas, renderer, target, x, y);
            },
            moved: function(x, y) {
                spineDemos.closest(canvas, renderer, skeleton, controlBones, hoverTargets, x, y);
            }
        });
    }

    function render() {
        skeleton.updateWorldTransform();

        renderer.camera.viewportWidth = bounds.x * 1.2;
        renderer.camera.viewportHeight = bounds.y * 1.2;
        renderer.resize(spine.ResizeMode.Fit);

        gl.clearColor(bgColor.r, bgColor.g, bgColor.b, bgColor.a);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.begin();
        renderer.drawSkeleton(skeleton, true);

        renderer.end();

        let stage = document.querySelector("canvas");

        let mc = new Hammer.Manager(stage);
        let pan = new Hammer.Pan({
            pointers: 2
        });

        let rotate = new Hammer.Rotate();
        let pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();

        mc.add([pan, pinch, rotate]);
        mc.get('pinch').set({
            enable: true
        });
        mc.get('rotate').set({
            enable: true
        });

        let adjustDeltaX = 0;
        let adjustDeltaY = 0;
        let adjustScale = 1;
        let adjustRotation = 0;

        let currentDeltaX = null;
        let currentDeltaY = null;
        let currentScale = null;
        let currentRotation = null;

        mc.on("panstart pinchstart rotatestart", function(e) {
            adjustRotation -= e.rotation;
        });

        mc.on("panmove pinchmove rotatemove", function(e) {
            currentRotation = adjustRotation + e.rotation;
            currentScale = adjustScale * e.scale;
            currentDeltaX = adjustDeltaX + (e.deltaX / currentScale);
            currentDeltaY = adjustDeltaY + (e.deltaY / currentScale);

            let transforms = ['scale(' + currentScale + ')'];
            if (transforms) {
                let e = canvas.clientWidth * currentScale;
                let t = canvas.clientHeight * currentScale;
                // resizescale = currentScale-1;

            }
            transforms.push('translate(' + currentDeltaX + 'px,' + currentDeltaY + 'px)');
            transforms.push('rotate(' + Math.round(currentRotation) + 'deg)');
            stage.style.transform = transforms.join(' ');
        });

        mc.on("panend pinchend rotateend", function(e) {
            adjustScale = currentScale;
            adjustRotation = currentRotation;
            adjustDeltaX = currentDeltaX;
            adjustDeltaY = currentDeltaY;
        });
    }

    init();
    vineDemo.assetManager = assetManager;
    vineDemo.loadingComplete = loadingComplete;
    vineDemo.render = render;
};
```

`util.js`:

```js
var spineDemos = {
    HOVER_COLOR_INNER: new spine.Color(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
    HOVER_COLOR_OUTER: new spine.Color(1, 1, 1, 1.0),
    NON_HOVER_COLOR_INNER: new spine.Color(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
    NON_HOVER_COLOR_OUTER: new spine.Color(0, 0, 0, 0.0),
    demos: [],
    loopRunning: false,
    canvases: [],
    downloader: new spine.Downloader(),
    path: "assets/"
};

(function() {
    var timeKeeper = new spine.TimeKeeper();

    function loop() {
        timeKeeper.update();
        if (spineDemos.log) console.log(timeKeeper.delta + ", " + timeKeeper.framesPerSecond);
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        var demos = spineDemos.demos;
        for (var i = 0; i < demos.length; i++) {
            var demo = demos[i];
            checkElementVisible(demo);
            renderDemo(demo);
        }
    }

    function renderDemo(demo) {
        if (demo.visible) {
            var canvas = demo.canvas;

            if (canvas.parentElement != demo.placeholder) {
                $(canvas).detach();
                demo.placeholder.appendChild(canvas);
            }
            let complete = demo.assetManager.isLoadingComplete();
            if (complete) {
                if (!demo.loaded) {
                    demo.loaded = true;
                    demo.loadingComplete();
                }
                if (spineDemos.log) console.log("Rendering: " + canvas.id);
                demo.render();
            }
            demo.loadingScreen.draw(complete);
        }
    }

    function checkElementVisible(demo) {
        const rect = demo.placeholder.getBoundingClientRect();
        const windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
        const windowWidth = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
        const vertInView = (rect.top <= windowHeight * 1.1) && ((rect.top + rect.height) >= windowHeight * -0.1);
        const horInView = (rect.left <= windowWidth * 1.1) && ((rect.left + rect.width) >= windowWidth * -0.1);

        demo.visible = (vertInView && horInView);
    }

    function createCanvases(numCanvases) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCanvases; i++) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            canvas.width = 0;
            canvas.height = 0;
            // canvas.context = new spine.ManagedWebGLRenderingContext(canvas, { alpha: true });
            canvas.context = new spine.ManagedWebGLRenderingContext(canvas, {
                alpha: true,
                premultipliedAlpha: false
            });
            canvas.id = "canvas-" + i;
            canvas.style.cssText = 'position: absolute;';
            spineDemos.canvases.push(canvas);
        }
    }

    spineDemos.init = function() {
        var numCanvases = 5;
        var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
        var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
        if (isFirefox && isAndroid) numCanvases = 2;
        createCanvases(numCanvases);

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    }

    spineDemos.addDemo = function(demo, placeholder) {
        var canvas = spineDemos.canvases[spineDemos.demos.length % spineDemos.canvases.length];
        demo(canvas);
        demo.placeholder = placeholder;
        demo.canvas = canvas;
        demo.visible = false;
        var renderer = new spine.SceneRenderer(canvas, canvas.context.gl);
        demo.loadingScreen = new spine.LoadingScreen(renderer);

        $(window).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', function() {
            checkElementVisible(demo);
            renderDemo(demo);
        });
        checkElementVisible(demo);
        spineDemos.demos.push(demo);
    }

    var coords = new spine.Vector3();
    var mouse = new spine.Vector3();
    spineDemos.closest = function(canvas, renderer, skeleton, controlBones, hoverTargets, x, y) {
        mouse.set(x, canvas.clientHeight - y, 0)
        var bestDistance = 250,
            index = 0;
        var best;
        for (var i = 0; i < controlBones.length; i++) {
            hoverTargets[i] = null;
            let bone = skeleton.findBone(controlBones[i]);
            var position = new spine.Vector2(bone.length, 0);
            bone.localToWorld(position);
            let distance = renderer.camera.worldToScreen(
                coords.set(bone.worldX, bone.worldY, 0),
                canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight).distance(mouse);
            if (distance < bestDistance) {
                bestDistance = distance;
                best = bone;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if (best) hoverTargets[index] = best;
        return best;
    };

    var position = new spine.Vector3();
    spineDemos.dragged = function(canvas, renderer, target, x, y) {
        if (target) {
            x = spine.MathUtils.clamp(x, 0, canvas.clientWidth)
            y = spine.MathUtils.clamp(y, 0, canvas.clientHeight);
            renderer.camera.screenToWorld(coords.set(x, y, 0), canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
            if (target.parent !== null) {
                target.parent.worldToLocal(position.set(coords.x, coords.y));
                target.x = position.x;
                target.y = position.y;
            } else {
                target.x = coords.x;
                target.y = coords.y;
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Try this code

```js
let transforms = 'scale(' + currentScale + ')';
if (transforms) {
    let e = canvas.clientWidth * currentScale;
    let t = canvas.clientHeight * currentScale;
    // resizescale = currentScale-1;
}
```

As the canvas scale increases and decreases, the (x, y) coordinates are given the same scale size, but are moved in different directions.

```js
x = x - canvas.width / 2 + centerX / resizescale;
y = canvas.height / 2 - y + centerY / resizescale;
```